# How to get URL parameters or send 'Get' request to graphql?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Here is the problem, I just wanna use 'Get' request to send parameters to graphql based server, since user may save the url as the bookmark and open it directly, like the example in Restful 'www.xxx.com?id=abc'.  But in local environment, my frontend listens port 3000, and backend(graphql) listens port 8000, so it cannot use 'www.localhost.com:3000/graphql?query={getId{id}}' to send request, so what could I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apollo GraphQL https://www.apollographql.com/docs/?no-cache=1

to write GraphQL queries so you can pass parameters

example: (React example)

```
function apolloFetch(query, variablesS, headers) {
  // http link with base
  const httpLink = ApolloLink.from([
    new HttpLink({
      uri: BASE_URL,
      headers,
    }),
  ]);

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: logoutLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const queryGQL = {
    query,
    variables: {
      ...variablesS,
    },
  };
  return client.query(queryGQL).then(res => res);
}
```

Query:

```
gql`
  query(
    $name: String
    $email: String
  ) {
    patients(
      name: $name
      email: $email
    ) {
      age
      birthDate
      hobbies {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```